# How to make a \\NAME share?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, network-share

Ok so I would like to create a share so if someone writes `\\NAME` they will reach a certain part of our fileshares.

Let's take for example `\\FS`

When this is written right now, nothing happens.
So how do we fix this, how do we make sure `\\FS` goes to our fileserver which would be

```
\\company.local\company\fs
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at Microsoft's distributed file system?

Comment: Spiff - just make that a statement, and put it as an answer :-)

Comment: I don't see any option to make it strictly \\FS there, 

Current setup: DFS Management => Namespaces => \\company.local\company => fs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. SMB connections are addressed in a `\\node-name\share` pattern. Even with DFS, you still use a namespace in place of the node name.

The closest you could get is making a DFS Namespace at `\\domain.com\namespace`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, guess there is no work around for that?

Comment: Not that I've ever seen.